# lua call function from a string with function name

Tags: dynamic, lua

Is it possible in lua to execute a function from a string representing its name?
i.e: I have the `string x = "foo"`, is it possible to do `x()` ?

If yes what is the syntax ?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

To call a function in the global namespace (as mentioned by @THC4k) is easily done, and does not require `loadstring()`.

```
x='foo'
_G[x]() -- calls foo from the global namespace
```

You would need to use `loadstring()` (or walk each table) if the function in another table, such as if `x='math.sqrt'`.

If `loadstring()` is used you would want to not only append parenthesis with ellipse `(...)` to allow for parameters, but also add `return` to the front.

```
x='math.sqrt'
print(assert(loadstring('return '..x..'(...)'))(25)) --> 5
```

or walk the tables:

```
function findfunction(x)
  assert(type(x) == "string")
  local f=_G
  for v in x:gmatch("[^%.]+") do
    if type(f) ~= "table" then
       return nil, "looking for '"..v.."' expected table, not "..type(f)
    end
    f=f[v]
  end
  if type(f) == "function" then
    return f
  else
    return nil, "expected function, not "..type(f)
  end
end

x='math.sqrt'
print(assert(findfunction(x))(121)) -->11
```

Comment: What if you want to call a non global function. For example, I need to call a function in another module, which has its own variables. If I make a copy of this function in the current namespace then I'll be making local copies of their variables too...

Answer (score 18):

I frequently put a bunch of functions in a table:

```
functions = {
       f1 = function(arg) print("function one: "..arg) end,
       f2 = function(arg) print("function two: "..arg..arg) end,
       ...,
       fn = function(arg) print("function N: argh") end,
}
```

Then you can use a string as an table index and run your function like this

```
print(functions["f1"]("blabla"))
print(functions["f2"]("blabla"))
```

This is the result:

```
function one: blabla
function two: blablablabla
```

I find this to be cleaner than using `loadstring()`. If you don't want to create a special function table you can use `_G['foo']`.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question as stated but does offer a simple workaround that I'll end up using.

Answer (score 12):

`loadstring` is not the answer here.  For starters you would need a `return` in the string, and other details I won't go into.

THC4k has the right idea; if you have the function name in the variable x, then the call you want is

```
_G[x](arg1, arg2, ...)
```

Answer (score 6):

Names are not unique, there can be many functions names foo in different namespaces. But `_G['foo']` is `foo` in the global namespace.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you want to do an 'eval', which is supported in Lua like so:

```
assert(loadstring(x))()
```

You'll probably want to concatenate the "()" onto x first, though.

Comment: What if you want to call a non global function. For example, I need to call a function in another module, which has its own variables. If I make a copy of this function in the current namespace then I'll be making local copies of their variables too...