# Lua call function from string on self?

Tags: lua

How can you call a function name via a string in Lua on `self`?

I tried the techniques described on the similar question ([lua call function from a string with function name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1791234/lua-call-function-from-a-string-with-function-name)), however this only addresses calling functions that exist on the global table, or through modules; it does not work on `self`.

Here is a simplified example of what I'm trying to do.

```
function CardsScene:onEnterFrame()
  if self.transition_complete then
    loadstring("self.basicMathInit")()
  end
end


function CardsScene:basicMathInit()
  print("Init has been called.")
end
```

This results in the following error.

```
scenes/CardsScene.lua:83: attempt to call a nil value
```

Comment: Pedantic: Functions are values; No value has a name. The left part of a function call—before the parentheses—is an expression. If the expression does not evaluate to a function value, the call is in error. Method call syntax is slightly different: The expression to the left of the colon should evaluate to a value, which, when indexed by the field name to the right of the colon, should evaluate to a function value. The first value is passed as the first parameter (`self` if the function definition uses the method syntax) and is typically a table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`self` is not magic. It's just a local variable, no different from any other Lua variable.

If you want to get a global function by its string name, you would access the global table with that string: `_G[string_name]`. `_G` is not magic; it's just a table.

Just like `self`. So you would do the *exact same thing* for getting access to members of `self` by name: `self[string_name]`. If that represents a function, you would call it with function call syntax: `self[string_name]()`.

Comment: Thanks, everything I had seen covers using loadstring to do this which was always failing.

Comment: with that syntax self does not seem to be populated in the method which is called. Any solution for that?

Comment: @JR: The question did not use `self:` syntax for calling the function, so it would be inappropriate for this answer to give `self` as a parameter to the function.