# LUA table string to obj

Tags: string, object, lua, key, lua-table

Is it possible to convert a key in object?
I would like to simplify this code:

This works:

```
for key, data in pairs(DBButtonOptions[self.value]) do
    if key == "widgetframe1" then
        widgetframe1:SetText(data)
        widgetframe1:SetDisabled(enable)
    elseif key == "widgetframe2" then
        widgetframe2:SetText(data)
        widgetframe2:SetDisabled(enable)
    elseif key == "widgetframe3" then
        widgetframe3:SetText(data)
        widgetframe3:SetDisabled(enable)
    elseif key == "widgetframe4" then
        widgetframe4:SetText(data)
        widgetframe4:SetDisabled(enable)
    elseif key == "widgetframe5" then
        widgetframe5:SetText(data)
        widgetframe5:SetDisabled(enable)
    end
end
```

This does *not* work:

```
for key, data in pairs(DBButtonOptions[self.value]) do
    key:SetText(data)
    key:SetDisabled(enable)
end
```

This works but error (Attempt to index local key):

`for key, data in pairs(DBButtonOptions[self.value]) do
  local key = _G[key]
  key:SetText(data)
  key:SetDisabled(enable)
end`

Comment: fixed  <code> local widgetframe1 </code> replaced by <code>widgetframe1</code> now error fixed

Comment: can you try using a different name for your local variable and use the last one, i.e. `local control = _G[key]`?  Also what do you mean by it works but you get an error?  Is it possible there is a key that isn't a control with SetText and SetDisabled functions?

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to take key like local variable. check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1791234/lua-call-function-from-a-string-with-function-name?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

I tried this snippet and it works fine

```
storeFn = _G
storeFn.Gn = {} -- limit iteration of loop "for" and don't get errors
storeFn.Gn.first = function(val) print("test first! "..val) end
storeFn.Gn.second= function(val) print("test second! "..val) end

for k, v in pairs(storeFn.Gn) do
     print( assert (loadstring('return '..'storeFn.Gn.'..k..'(...)')) (math.random()) )
end
```

Only have be careful with memory leaks

```
storeFn.Gn = nil
for k,_ in pairs(storeFn) do print(k) end -- restart to original _G
```

Also can use `_G.Fn={}` and after destroy it `_G.Fn=nil`